# Cant get angular2 animation to FadeIn

Tags: javascript, animation, angular

So I have been searching and trying for hours. I am trying to get the html to fadeIn but it is always opacity:1 immediately when ngFor displays it, and never fades it. FadingOut is not an issue.

```
@Component({
selector:'c-translation-wizard',
templateUrl: 'scripts/translationWizard/TTranslationWizard.html',
animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
        state('active', style({ opacity: 1 })),
        state('inactive', style({ opacity: 0 })),
        transition('active => inactive', [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            animate('0.7s ease-out')
        ]),
        transition('inactive => active', [
            animate('0.7s ease-in', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition('void => *', [
            style({ opacity: 1 }),
            animate('0.7s ease-in')
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
            animate('0.7s ease-out', style({ opacity: 0 }))
        ]),
        transition('void => active', [
            style({ opacity: 1 }),
            animate('0.7s ease-in')
        ]),
        transition('inactive => void', [
            animate('0.7s ease-out', style({ opacity: 0 }))
        ])
    ])
])
export class CTranslationWizard implements InterfaceLocalStorage, OnInit, OnDestroy {

results : CTranslationWizard_results[];
result$ : any;
importExport : string;
type: string;
errors : string[] = [];
log : Logger;
sHtsTranslation : SHtsTranslation;
toggle = false;
gA : any;

constructor(GoogleAnalytics : GoogleAnalytics,
            log : Logger,
            sHtsTranslation : SHtsTranslation
){
    this.log = log;
    this.gA = GoogleAnalytics;
    this.sHtsTranslation = sHtsTranslation;
    this.importExport = "export";
    this.results = [];

    this.type = '-';
    //LocalStorage.getItem(this);
}


setImportExport(value : string){
    this.importExport = value;
}

onlyNumberic(ip:string) : boolean{
    let isNumber : boolean =  /^\d+$/.test(ip);
    return isNumber;
}

isEightTenDigits(ip:string) : boolean{
    let isET : boolean = (ip.length == 8 || ip.length == 10);
    return isET;
}

isSixDigits(ip:string) : boolean {
    let isET : boolean =  (ip.length == 6);
    return isET;
}

isFiveDigits(ip:string) : boolean{
    let isET : boolean =  ip.length == 5;
    return isET;
}

errorText() {
    let err : string[] = [];
    err.push("An SITC number can only be 5 digits long");
    err.push("An NAICS number can only be 6 digits long");
    err.push("An HTC number can only be 8 or 10 digits long.");
    return err;
}

getType(value : string) : string {
    if(this.onlyNumberic(value)) {
        let val : number = parseInt(value);
        let type : string = getType(val);
        return (type ? type : "-");
    } else {
        return '-';
    }
}

validateInput(value : string) : string[] {
    let err : string[] = [];

    if(!this.onlyNumberic(value)){
        err.push("Only numeric characters maybe used.");
        return err;
    }

    let eightTen : boolean = this.isEightTenDigits(value);
    if(eightTen) {
        return [];
    }

    let six : boolean = this.isSixDigits(value);
    if(six) {
        return [];
    }

    let five : boolean = this.isFiveDigits(value);
    if(five) {
        return [];
    }

    return this.errorText();
}

submit(value : string) {

    this.gA.pageEvent(
        "info",
        "click",
        "translationWizard_submitButton",
    );

    this.errors = this.validateInput(value);
    if(this.errors.length == 0){

        let val : number = parseInt(value);
        //do query for results, delete this
        //hit service get result
        //this.results.push(new MImportExport('htic',12345678,this.outputType, 12345, 12345));
        this.sHtsTranslation.htsTranslation(val, this.importExport, 101);
        //save the new model to local storage
        //LocalStorage.setItem(this);

    }
}

removeByIndex(index : number){

    this.gA.pageEvent(
        "info",
        "click",
        "translationWizard_removeButton"
    );
    this.results.splice(index,1);

}

removeAll(){
    this.gA.pageEvent(
        "info",
        "click",
        "translationWizard_removeAllButton"
    );
    this.results.splice(0);
}

//OnInit, OnDestroy interfaces
ngOnInit(){
    this.result$ = this.sHtsTranslation.htsTranslation$.subscribe(
        (modelHts : ModelHts) => {
            this.log.debug(this, "pushing modelHts into results");
            this.results.unshift(modelHts);
        });
    this.log.debug(this, "sHtsTranslation subscribed");
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.result$){
        this.result$.unsubscribe();
        this.log.debug(this, "sHtsTranslation unsubscribed");
    }
}

//interface LocalStorage
getExclusionList(): string[] {
    return ['errors','outputType', 'gA', 'sHtsTranslation'];
}

}

export interface CTranslationWizard_results {
inputNumber : number;
inputType : string;
resultsForIE : [{
    htc8 : number,
    htc10 : number,
    sitc : number,
    naics : number
}]
}


<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Input Type</th>
                            <th>Input Number</th>
                            <th>I/E</th>
                            <th class="fixed">SITC</th>
                            <th class="fixed">NAICS</th>
                            <th class="fixed">HTC-8</th>
                            <th class="fixed">HTC-10</th>
                            <th>
                                <button
                                        (click)="removeAll()"
                                        type="button"
                                        id="translationWizard_removeAllButton"
                                        class="btn btn-default remove start end">
                                        <span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                                            aria-hidden="true">
                                        </span>
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let modelHts_ of results; let i = index;"
                            [@flyInOut]="modelHts_.state">
                            <th scope="row">{{i}}</th>
                            <td>{{modelHts_.inputType}}</td>
                            <td>{{modelHts_.inputNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{modelHts_.importExport}}</td>
                            <td class="table-nested" colspan="4">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <tr *ngFor="let resultForIE of modelHts_.resultsForIE;">
                                        <td class="fixed">{{resultForIE.sitc}}</td>
                                        <td class="fixed">{{resultForIE.naics}}</td>
                                        <td class="fixed">{{resultForIE.htc8}}</td>
                                        <td class="fixed">{{resultForIE.htc10}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <th>
                                <button
                                    (click)="removeByIndex(i)"
                                    type="button"
                                    id="translationWizard_removeButton"
                                    class="btn btn-default remove start end">
                                        <span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                                            aria-hidden="true">
                                        </span>
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

In the template above, this bit of code is where its supposed to fade-in on adding to the array.

```
<tr *ngFor="let modelHts_ of results; let i = index;"
                                [@flyInOut]="modelHts_.state">
```

any Ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

New to the animations module, However, I did not want to embed a view state variable into my data model coming from the server, as there can be many views using the model (not a good idea from my point of view).

Animations seem confused regarding the VOID state and NgFor. I will try to make this explanation as simple as possible.

The VOID state is the html + styling without angular transformations applied. In this case, ngFor adds the element to the dom then the state is changed and the styling is applied to go to that state. If [@flyInOut]='active' and style="opacity:0;" on the element (when added by ngFor) it will transition to opacity:1.

However, when removed from the dom by ngFor it does not transition back to the void state. Instead, I must transition the variable manually controlling the state and set a timer to remove it from the array (ngFor) after the animation would complete.

Here is the final changes to the code above that results in a working transition in and out.

```
<tr #localRow
                            style="opacity: 0"
                            title="true"
                            *ngFor="let modelHts_ of results; let i = index;"
                            [@flyInOut]="localRow.title">
```

I bound the "title" on the element as the variable controlling the local variables state (no need embed the state controller in modelHts_).

```
<button
                                    (click)="localRow.title = removeByIndex(i)"
                                    type="button"
                                    id="translationWizard_removeButton"
                                    class="btn btn-default remove start end">
                                        <span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                                            aria-hidden="true">
                                        </span>
                                </button>
```

the button that removes the element changes the title/state.

```
        state('true', style({ opacity: 1 })),
        state('false', style({ opacity: 0 })),
        transition('void => true', [
            animate('.75s')
        ]),
        transition('true => void', [
            animate('.75s')
        ]),
        transition('true => false', [
            animate('.75s')
        ]),
        transition('false => true', [
            animate('.75s')
        ])


    removeByIndex(index : number) : boolean{

    this.gA.pageEvent(
        "info",
        "click",
        "translationWizard_removeButton"
    );
    setTimeout(()=> {
        this.results.splice(index,1);
    },1000);
    return false;
}
```

In the controller, I set a timeout to remove the item from the array after the animation would have completed transitioning state.

Anyone see where I went wrong? Or is this a bug with ngFor (should transition to VOID state).

Also, other suggestions for not embedding the state into the model would be appreciated... via comments.

Answer (score 0):

Without code of your controller it is hard to say. I assume it has to do with `modelHts_.state`. What does it look like?

If you just care about the entering animation, you could also do `[@flyInOut]="true"`.

Comment: I have tried setting [@flyInOut]="true" before/again but it does not work..

Comment: besides this point, I thought animations were only concerned here with the array (in this case) and with the component animation meta data?